# How to generate code for less_eq operation

Tags: isabelle

I need to generate a code calculating all values greater or equal to some value:

```
datatype ty = A | B | C

instantiation ty :: order
begin

fun less_ty where
  "A < x = (x = C)"
| "B < x = (x = C)"
| "C < x = False"

definition "(x :: ty) ≤ y ≡ x = y ∨ x < y"

instance
  apply intro_classes
  apply (metis less_eq_ty_def less_ty.elims(2) ty.distinct(3) ty.distinct(5))
  apply (simp add: less_eq_ty_def)
  apply (metis less_eq_ty_def less_ty.elims(2))
  using less_eq_ty_def less_ty.elims(2) by fastforce

end

instantiation ty :: enum
begin

definition [simp]: "enum_ty ≡ [A, B, C]"
definition [simp]: "enum_all_ty P ≡ P A ∧ P B ∧ P C"
definition [simp]: "enum_ex_ty P ≡ P A ∨ P B ∨ P C" 

instance
  apply intro_classes
  apply auto
  by (case_tac x, auto)+

end

lemma less_eq_code_predI [code_pred_intro]:
  "Predicate_Compile.contains {z. x ≤ z} y ⟹ x ≤ y"
(*  "Predicate_Compile.contains {z. z ≤ y} x ⟹ x ≤ y"*)
  by (simp_all add: Predicate_Compile.contains_def)

code_pred [show_modes] less_eq
  by (simp add: Predicate_Compile.containsI)

values "{x. A ≤ x}"
(* values "{x. x ≤ C}" *)
```

It works fine. But the theory looks over-complicated. Also I can't calculate values less or equal to some value. If one will uncoment the 2nd part of `less_eq_code_predI` lemma, then `less_eq` will have only one mode `i => i => boolpos`.

Is there a simpler and more generic approach?

Can `less_eq` support `i => o => boolpos` and `o => i => boolpos` at the same time?

Is it possible not to declare `ty` as an instance of `enum` class? I can declare a function returning a set of elements greater or equal to some element:

```
fun ge_values where
  "ge_values A = {A, C}"
| "ge_values B = {B, C}"
| "ge_values C = {C}"

lemma ge_values_eq_less_eq_ty:
  "{y. x ≤ y} = ge_values x"
  by (cases x; auto simp add: dual_order.order_iff_strict)
```

This would allow me to remove `enum` and `code_pred` stuff. But in this case I will not be able to use this function in the definition of other predicates. How to replace `(≤)` by `ge_values` in the following definition?

```
inductive pred1 where
  "x ≤ y ⟹ pred1 x y"

code_pred [show_modes] pred1 .
```

I need `pred1` to have at least `i => o => boolpos` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate compiler has an option `inductify` that tries to convert functional definitions into inductive ones. It is somewhat experimental and does not work in every case, so use it with care. In the above example, the type classes make the whole situation a bit more complicated. Here's what I managed to get working:

```
case_of_simps less_ty_alt: less_ty.simps

definition less_ty' :: "ty ⇒ ty ⇒ bool" where "less_ty' = (<)"

declare less_ty_alt [folded less_ty'_def, code_pred_def]

code_pred [inductify, show_modes] "less_ty'" .

values "{x. less_ty' A x}"
```

1. The first line convertes the pattern-matching equations into one with a case expression on the right. It uses the command `case_of_simps` from `HOL-Library.Simps_Case_Conv`.
2. Unfortunately, the predicate compiler seems to have trouble with compiling type class operations. At least I could not get it to work. 
   So the second line introduces a new constant for `(<)` on `ty`.
3. The attribute `code_pred_def` tells the predicate compiler to use the given theorem (namely `less_ty_alt` with `less_ty'` instead of `(<)`) as the "defining equation".
4. `code_pred` with the `inductify` option looks at the equation for `less_ty'` declared by `code_pred_def` and derives an inductive definition out of that. `inductify` usually works well with case expressions, constructors and quantifiers. Everything beyond that is at your own risk.

Alternatively, you could also manually implement the enumeration similar to `ge_values` and register the connection between `(<)` and `ge_values` with the predicate compiler. See the `setup` block at the end of the `Predicate_Compile` theory in the distribution for an example with `Predicate.contains`. Note however that the predicate compiler works best with *predicates* and not with *sets*. So you'd have to write `ge_values` in the predicate monad `Predicate.pred`.